# jQuery validate dynamic percentage field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin. I'm trying to calculate the sum of all inputs fields using the class .percent. If the sum of the .percent fields isn't equal to 100%, throw validation error.

The percent rows are a part of a dynamic grid and can very in number. You'll see a sample of what I've been working on below. I'm finding the addMethod is called for every input.percent rather than a single time. I'd also like to say it's being called before submit is called.

the code.

html

```
<div class="row">
    <input value="" class="percent"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input value="" class="percent"/>
</div>
```

js

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    percent: {percent:true}
});

$.validator.addMethod("percent",
    function cals(value, element) {
        // all the fields that start with 'coeff'
        var percent = element;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < percent.length; i++) {
            total += Number(percent[i].value);
        }
    return  total == 100;
}, $.format("Percentage fields most total up to 100%"));

$("form").validate({

});
```

Updates

I've tried the following code with minor success

```
$("#modify-funding .percent").rules('add', {sum: 100});

$.validator.addMethod("sum", function (value, element, params) {
        var sumOfVals = 0;

        $("#modify-funding .percent").each(function () {
            sumOfVals = sumOfVals + parseInt($(this).val().length ? $(this).val() : 0);
        });
        if (sumOfVals == params) return true;
        return false;
    },
    $.format("Percentage fields most total up to 100%")
);
```

when passing the class into rules it's only passing in a single element which doesn't enable me to query for the additional percent fields. The other issue is it only adds the error class to the first .percent element and the additional elements will not release the error once the 100% criteria has been met.

Update 2

This is the closest I've come to getting percent validation working. It isn't very efficient code since it needs to loop through all the percent fields every time you loop the rules. The code still validates before a submit action has taken place plus does not clear all the percent errors on keyup when the percent has been corrected to equal 100.

```
$("#modify-funding .percent").each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {sum: [".percent"]});
})

$.validator.addMethod("sum", function (value, element, params) {
    var sumOfVals = 0;
        $(params[0]).each(function() {
            sumOfVals += parseFloat($(this).val().length ? $(this).val() : 0);
        });

        if (sumOfVals == 100) return true;
        return false;
    },
    $.format("Percentage fields most total up to 100%")
);
```

Comment: You've added a class rule for `percent`. This means that every input with class `percent` will run your validation rule. How do you want it to work?

Comment: on submit, I'd like it to get a sum of all the fields with .percent and if not equal to 100% throw validation error.

Comment: When using `.rules()` method, you must wrap it in an `.each()`, otherwise it only gets applied to first element with the matching class, as you've seen.

Comment: @Sparky672 I agree you would need to wrap the rules in a loop to pass the proper element in, however I'm concerned it would needs to call the same addMethod multiple times which would then need to loop the percent fields multiple times.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking in your OP.  Does it work or not?  Is this just a matter of trying to make it more efficient?  Please try to condense it down to just one main concise issue.

Comment: @Sparkey672 It works, but not entirely the way I'd like it to work. Additionally calling the sub loop every time you loop through the rule seems inefficient. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Sparkey672 oh, I added an additional update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jquery for such a simple validation. I don't really understand what all the hype is about jquery. It just makes your code look all ugly.

```
    function validate() {
        var ret = false;
        var total = 0;
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
        for (i in elems) 
            if (elems[i].className == "percent") 
                total += parseFloat( elems[i].value);
        if (total == 100)
            ret = true;
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: what are you using to call the function. I was only trying to use the jQuery validate plugin because it's used for many other validations within the project.

Comment: I don't really use jQuery, but a quick look at the validator plugin says there is a .validate() which is a bool, so somewhere on your submit you're checking for this. So you'd just to if( XXX.validate() && myAnswerValidate()) then do {...}. This is outside the 'framework' but will work.